# For every row keep only the non-nas and then concatenate while ignoring index, pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, np.nan, np.nan],
                   'results': ['Sub', 'Sub', 'Sub'],
                   'group': ['a', 'a', 'a'],
                   'seed': [6, 6, 6],
                   'col2': [np.nan, 2, np.nan],
                   'col3': [np.nan, np.nan, 3]})

df

    col1    results group   seed    col2    col3
0   1.0     Sub     a       6       NaN     NaN
1   NaN     Sub     a       6       2.0     NaN
2   NaN     Sub     a       6       NaN     3.0
```

I would like for every row to keep only the columns that dont have NaNs and then concatenate back ignoring the index

The end result looks like this

```
pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1],
             'results':['Sub',],
            'group':['a'],
            'seed':[6],
            'col2':[2],
            'col3':[3]}, index=[0])

    col1    results group   seed    col2    col3
0   1       Sub     a       6       2       3
```

How could I do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [`bfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html) and slice the first row:

```
out = df.bfill().iloc[[0]]
```

Output:

```
   col1 results group  seed  col2  col3
0   1.0     Sub     a     6   2.0   3.0
```